# Can I take a picture without showing the view finder on BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Is it possible to take a picture programmatically from the device camera without showing the view finder on an application screen in BlackBerry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you must start the camera preview and display it on a Screen before a photo can be taken programmatically.